# Notification badge/counter in control app

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I am working on a control-based (V2.0) SW2 app. Is it possible to set the badge-number (i.e. the notification counter) on the icon in the application view used in a notification-based app? I do not need anything else from the notification API, I just want to be able to set the badge-number and removing it after the user opens the control-based app.

Thank you,
Andrej

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not currently possible without using both the Control and Notification APIs together.  If you use both of them in your extension you may be able to achieve something similar to what you want but with the limitation that the extension will always start in Notification mode (this is a bug in the current implementation) so you wouldn't be able to go straight into the Control part of your extension.

Comment: any plans for fixes for that bug?

Comment: The problem is that I always want to start in control mode because the notification mode is too restrictive. Why not add a Control Intent to the API? We have a CONTROL_VIBRATE_INTENT and a CONTROL_LED_INTENT for vibration and led control, so why not a CONTROL_BADGE_INTENT?